# Trigger to deactivate row after timestamp is hit

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table called `pages` in mysql with columns:

```
ID int NOT NULL PK,
end_time TIMESTAMP,
active BIT
```

I'm setting the end_time as an expiration timestamp, so when a row is created `active` is set to 1 and `end_time` to the expiration date/time.

Is there a way to create a trigger or something similar so that when the end_time is simply reached it sets active to 0?

I don't know if triggers would be the best way to go, or how I should set that up, but it seems within the realm of what I should be doing.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Just use a condition in your queries that checks if the timestamp is in the past. That'll already tell you, if a row is active or not. There's no need for that column at all.

Comment: Well I'm actually using the active column for the user to also delete pages. However, when they create a page they can create an expiration date for it to automatically expire. So active is taking 2 different forms of functionality here. If the user doesn't manually delete a page (deactivate it) I want it to deactivate at the expiration time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) as a periodic time based deletion/set `active=0`.

If the end_time needs to be strict, keep `active=0 AND end_time <= NOW()` in your queries that retrieve the entries.